# Telegram API release.keystore ERROR

Tags: android, api, gradle, keystore, telegram

I tried to code a little bit at the Telegram API in Android Studio, but first of all I just filled in the BuildVars ( The readme.txt sayed that I have to do that ). And run the Projekt and than came this ERROR:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':TMessagesProj:packageDebug'.
> File 'C:\Users\yanni\Desktop\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\config\release.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

I tried erverything but it doesen´t work. Even when I used the build Signed APK option (from Android Studio) and I install it on my phone the APP always close instandly. Why? Please help me and sorry for my English :D.

BUILDVARS:

```
package org.telegram.messenger;

public class BuildVars {
    public static boolean DEBUG_VERSION = false;
    public static int BUILD_VERSION = 695;
    public static int APP_ID = *****; //obtain your own APP_ID at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
    public static String APP_HASH = "**********"; //obtain your own APP_HASH at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
    public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH = "your-hockeyapp-api-key-here";
    public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH_DEBUG = "your-hockeyapp-api-key-here";
    public static String GCM_SENDER_ID = "760348033672";
    public static String SEND_LOGS_EMAIL = "yannick.thespy007@gmail.com";
    public static String BING_SEARCH_KEY = ""; //obtain your own KEY at https://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_KEY = ""; //obtain your own KEY at https://developer.foursquare.com/
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_ID = ""; //obtain your own API_ID at https://developer.foursquare.com/
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_VERSION = "20150326";
}
```

GRADLEBUILD:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.6.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
            storePassword "bebi22052014"
            keyAlias "Yannick"
            keyPassword "bebi22052014"
         }

        release {
            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
            storePassword "bebi22052014"
            keyAlias "Yannick"
            keyPassword "bebi22052014"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        foss {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    sourceSets.debug {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.release {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.foss {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 695
        versionName "3.3.2"
    }
}
```

Thankyou,

Yannick!

Update:

Hello I filled in the whole BuildVars:

```
package org.telegram.messenger;

public class BuildVars {
    public static boolean DEBUG_VERSION = false;
    public static int BUILD_VERSION = 695;
    public static int APP_ID = *****; //obtain your own APP_ID at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
    public static String APP_HASH = "***************************; //obtain your own APP_HASH at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
    public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH = "**************";
    public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH_DEBUG = "*************";
    public static String GCM_SENDER_ID = "760348033672";
    public static String SEND_LOGS_EMAIL = "yannick.thespy007@gmail.com";
    public static String BING_SEARCH_KEY = "******************"; //obtain your own KEY at https://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_KEY = "************"; //obtain your own KEY at https://developer.foursquare.com/
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_ID = "***********"; //obtain your own API_ID at https://developer.foursquare.com/
    public static String FOURSQUARE_API_VERSION = "20150326";
}
```

The knew ERROR:

```
12-21 20:25:22.854 15507-15507/org.telegram.messenger.beta E/art: No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)
12-21 20:25:22.854 15507-15507/org.telegram.messenger.beta D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-21 20:25:22.855 15507-15507/org.telegram.messenger.beta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: org.telegram.messenger.beta, PID: 15507
                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)
                                                                                 at org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(Native Method)
                                                                                 at org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:278)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4756)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: I assume the file exists?

Comment: I think the projekt must create it.... The gradlebuild say it ,:D

Comment: `The gradlebuild say it`?  what do you mean?

Comment: The code-part in the gradle.build is:

    release {
                storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
                storePassword "bebi22052014"
                keyAlias "Yannick"
                keyPassword "bebi22052014"
            }

So Android Studio have to create the .keystore. The Android Studio page say the same : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

The whole code is from telegram.org and them say the code is functional... What do I wrong?

Comment: `So Android Studio have to create the .keystore` no. Gradle will look for the keystore file at this location. It is your job to create it and to place it there. Also, using the release keystore in debug is a bit surprising.

Comment: Your awsome Thank you! But there is a knew error so the APP instantly shut down when it´s open ,:D

I´ll add it in the end from my question :)

Comment: you should ask a new question for that. But before you should make sure you read the stacktrace, that you understand it, and that you tried the obvious solutions before posting the new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable some code in build.gradle

```
/*  signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("config/debug.keystore")
    }

    release {
        storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}*/

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
       // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
       // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    foss {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
       // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```